# Javascript code running under Android

Tags: javascript, android

i would like to make Android app for my web-based project. It is written in JS, and requests data from .NET - WCFServices. I would like to ask, if there is a way, how to use the same code, i have for web application. Basicly it would be like browser, but the frame (title, and design, and stuff like that), would be mine.

Any ideas, how to do it?

Regards Watchick

Comment: Ever heard of [PhoneGap](http://www.nitobi.com/products/phonegap/)?

Answer (score 0):

You web app could be native android app with this easy solution: http://www.appsgeyser.com/
They will wrap your html/js/css inside a web view and it will be native.
Good luck.